# Why do exceptions in dart constructors not get caught?

Tags: flutter, dart

When instantiating a dart class in an try catch block, exceptions seem to not get caught. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass{
  MyClass(){
    throw 'Exception';
  }
}

testCatchException(){
  try {
    MyClass myClass = MyClass();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('Exception caught');
  }
}
```

Expected behavior:

Catch the exception and continue with execution.

Real behavior:

Exception doesn't get caught.

What is the proper way to catch the exception here?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you throw an `Exception` instead of a string, your catch block will work:

```
class MyClass{
  MyClass(){
    throw Exception('Exception');
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    final myClass = MyClass();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('Exception caught');
  } 
}
```

If you *want* to throw and catch a `String` instead (which I don't recommend), you need to remove the clause that makes the catch listen on Exceptions:

```
class MyClass{
  MyClass(){
    throw 'Exception Text String';
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    final myClass = MyClass();
  } catch (e) {
    print('Something caught:');
    print(e);
  } 
}
```